# Capturing HTML Text Input Key press after key has been applied?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

A total newbie question, so please bear with me here ;)

When a key press occurs in a HTML text input control, there are two events that seem useful in managing it (onKeyPress and onChanged). onKeyPress fires after the key has been pressed, but before the operation has been applied to the control's text. The later is only fired when focus is removed from the control and edits were made.

My question: Is there a way to capture the event, after the key press has been applied to the control but w/o removing focus (so I can work off of the resultant text)? Or is this pretty much the options I have to work off of?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to do?  From what it sounds like, `onKeyUp` may be your solution.

Comment: It's a text box that can have trivial mathematical formulas typed into it - I was hoping to verify the syntax, as it's typed in and then turn the background on the control red as soon as the first error is detected. Backspace and Deleted are allowed to be typed, of course.

Of course, it's helpful to work on the final text (rather than the text before the edit), so I was hoping there was an event that would capture that.

Comment: Scroll down this page for a list of available events http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to look at `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` events. I suspect you're interested in `onkeyup.` Perhaps you could provide more info and I could give a more complete example.

Comment: Actually, that's all I needed - Thank you!